# SAP Business Object 4.2 connective with Hbase through phoenix

Tags: hbase, business-objects, sap-lumira

How can I connect SAP Business object 4.2 / SAP Lumira to Phoenix ( Hbase ). 
Is there a phoenix driver is available and from where could I get that? what steps do I need to follow?

Answer (score 0):

On my side I did solve that problem using Simba ODBC Driver (Phoenix with Knox) and Universe Design Tool (also available with SAP BO 4.2 SP5 Client Tools). When I was using the SAP BO IDT I was getting error message "Write operation not allowed" when trying to discover the database's schema. In UDT I am able to see all the tables and create the Universe. More of that, this question was raised by my company to SAP (why UDT works fine in this case wheras IDT doesn't).